# valueError: time data '2021-02-01T04:10:39.669Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%M:%H:%S%f%z'

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert a string into date type format but stuck with the error

```
valueError: time data '2021-02-01T04:10:39.669Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%M:%H:%S%f%z'
```

I am sharing my code.
Any help will be appreciable.
Thanks in Advance.

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "2021-02-01T04:10:39.669Z"
format = "%Y-%m-%dT%M:%H:%S%f%z"
created_datetime = datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
print(created_datetime)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your format has two errors. You must use the first hour then the minute. Now Since your timezone is started from dot so use `.%f` and timezone `z` with together `.%fz`. If you don't aware of the timezone then use always capital `Z`

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "2021-02-01T04:10:39.669Z"
created_datetime = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
print(created_datetime)

# Output
# 2021-02-01 04:10:39.669000
```